# Ads providers for mobile application

Tags: iphone, android, ios, admob, ads

I would like to monetize my free mobile application with help of ads.

What mobile ad solutions are available on the market?
Do they have a dedicated SDK for Android or iPhone?

The only solution that I know of is AdMob.

Are there any solutions dedicated to the European market?

Comment: there are solutions directed to the chinese market, checkout MOBUS. not sure if there is anything similar for the Central Europe. My advice would be to stick with AdMob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many avaliable like:

[Admob](http://www.admob.com/)

[Greystrip](http://www.greystripe.com/)

[Mobclix](http://www.mobclix.com)

and for iPhone specifically [iAd](http://advertising.apple.com/)

Comment: @Aurum\ Aquila Thanks for edit, BTW that was a serious typing mistake :(